# Ricksaw: axes not rendering weeks

Tags: javascript, d3.js, rickshaw

I'm displaying a graph that dynamically deals with a wide range of values, and the x axis is all dates. When the graph is only displaying days of the months, hours, years, or months, it's fine, but between days of the month and months it stops rendering both axes. I know this because I'm using the slider to change how much data is displayed, and over certain ranges the slider stops showing movement and the axes aren't displayed.

I'm using the regular axes functions and epoch seconds in by data. any advice would be appreciated.

the below is the code i'm using to render the axes.

```
   var xAxis_{{device_strip}} = new Rickshaw.Graph.Axis.Time({
        graph:graph_{{device_strip}},
        timeFixture: new Rickshaw.Fixtures.Time.Local()
    });
    xAxis_{{device_strip}}.render();

    var yAxis_{{device_strip}} = new Rickshaw.Graph.Axis.Y({
        graph:graph_{{device_strip}},
    });
    yAxis_{{device_strip}}.render();
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that the issue I was having was caused by the version of d3 the project was using. It should have been using version 3 and it was instead it was using version 4.